# Help understanding constant q output

Tags: audio, wavelet, algorithms

I'm trying to visualise and understand the output of constant q transform. Based on my experience with FFT and the articles I've read so far, I would expect that each output bin would represent one frequency band (logarithmically spaced). Which means a naive way o finding the fundamental frequency would be to find the bin with highest energy in the spectrum.

The constant q algorithm I'm using has complex output, and I assume that the real part is the magnitude and the imaginary part is the phase. So, I compute the spectrum, but odd enough, the result looks exactly the same for every note or chord I play on the piano:

[image]

Which pretty much debunks my initial idea of finding the highest energy bin (it's always the last one).

What am I doing wrong? Is this really how the output should look?

EDIT:

Here is the code I use:

```
chromaSize = 24
frameSize = 8192 * 4 * (chromaSize / 12)

fft = es.FFT(size = frameSize)
cq = es.ConstantQ(binsPerOctave = chromaSize)
ip = es.InstantPower()

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, channels=1,
                rate=44100, input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=frameSize)

plt.ion()
plt.show(block = False)

while True:
    frame = np.fromstring(stream.read(frameSize, False), dtype=np.float32)

    if len(frame) >= 0 and ip(frame) > 0.0001:
        f = fft(frame)[1:]
        r = np.abs(cq(f))

        plt.clf()
        ind = np.arange(len(r))
        plt.bar(ind, r, color='blue', alpha=0.5)
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.0001)
```

I'm using essentia's implementation. Ultimately, my goal would be to extract the fundamental and it's harmonics, which will then get compared using markov chains with a given data set.

Comment: Try using `abs()` for magnitude and `angle()` for phase. Real part for magnitude seems incorrect.

Comment: Does that mean that, if i'm only interested in the bin with the max value, I can simply discard the imaginary part and use `abs()` on the real part?

Comment: `abs()` gets the magnitude of the complex value. Can you edit your question to provide more context on your algorithm and what exactly you have tried so far?

Comment: @Juancho. Thank you for your comment. If you mean `abs` as in `np.abs`, I'm already using that. I've edited my question with the code I use to plot that graph. I'll try to do the same thing using librosa this time.